# Create an instance of a random class

Tags: python

i'm currently making a text-based game on python and i have a question.
I have classes for some rooms like RoomSpider, RoomSoldier, RoomDragon, etc. and I want to create a map (3d array) and fill some rooms with an instance of a random class.

For example:

```
[[RoomSpider, RoomSoldier],
[RoomSoldier,RoomDragon]]
```

How can I do to create an instance of a random class?

Comment: Looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/python-dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make an instance of a random class:

```
import random
classes = (RoomSpider, RoomSoldier, RoomDragon, 
           RoomElephant, RoomPixie)

# choose a random class from the list and instantiate it
instance = random.choice(classes)()
```

Comment: How about classes with arguments? What if it randomly chose one class which has more arguments than the others?

Comment: @Alteros Using this approach then either all your classes need to expose a common constructor api (using `*args` or `**kw` if required), or you'll need factory functions with a common api

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), it lets you choose a random element from a sequence.

```
from random import choice
classes = (RoomSpider, RoomSoldier, RoomDragon, ...)
room = [[choice(classes)() for _ in range(2)] for __ in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes are first-class objects in Python, which means that you can store them in variables and pass them around. So for instance, you could make a list/tuple of all your possible classes and then pick random ones:

```
import random

room_classes = (RoomSpider, RoomSoldier, RoomDragon)
room_map = []

for row in range(5):
    room_row = []
    for col in range(5):
        room_class = random.choice(room_classes) # picks a random class
        room_row.append(room_class())            # creates an instance of that class
    room_map.append(room_row)
```

This uses [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to generate a 5x5 set of randomly chosen instances.