# Using Python Factory Idioms

Tags: python, python-3.x, factory, factory-pattern

Below is a pattern from :https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html . My question is this, is this still the best idiom/pattern to do generic object creation in Python 3.x?  I can't seem to find much on this topic.  The code is below:

```
class Shape(object):
    # Create based on class name:
    def factory(type):
        #return eval(type + "()")
        if type == "Circle": return Circle()
        if type == "Square": return Square()
        assert 0, "Bad shape creation: " + type
    factory = staticmethod(factory)

class Circle(Shape):
    def draw(self): print("Circle.draw")
    def erase(self): print("Circle.erase")

class Square(Shape):
    def draw(self): print("Square.draw")
    def erase(self): print("Square.erase")

# Generate shape name strings:
def shapeNameGen(n):
    types = Shape.__subclasses__()
    for i in range(n):
        yield random.choice(types).__name__

shapes = \
  [ Shape.factory(i) for i in shapeNameGen(7)]

for shape in shapes:
    shape.draw()
    shape.erase()
```

You can also create a factory by using the `__class__` method as well I've noticed, but I'm unsure of the best way to use this.

Comment: I don't see much use for the `factory` method or `shapeNameGen` here. Why not just `types = Shape.__subclasses__()`; `shapes = [random.choice(types)() for _ in range(7)]`? Why hardcode the strings `'Circle'` and `'Square'` if you don't have to? The factories for `Circle` and `Square` are `Circle` and `Square`.

Comment: I have a situation where I could have multiple geometries being given. This is an over simplified example, but I am getting JSON response of various geometries, and instead of having to write multiple if statements multiple times, I thought using a Factory could reduce the issue: so Shape(JSON) -> Circle or Shape(JSON) - Square, etc...

Comment: I still think this factory is awkward.You could have a dictionary `{'Circle': Circle, ...}` or instantiate a class [dynamically by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/python-dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported).

Comment: @timeb Thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to check out the dynamically by name link.

Comment: the reason you don’t find much existing info  is this pattern isn’t very useful in Python.  Now, if you had a complex set of rules that the Shape class had to work out and really didn’t concern the rest of the code, then maybe.  As in dumping a chunk of json and letting the factory’s internals decide.  But it’s overkill in this case.  Also Python classes often struggle a bit knowing about themselves, making this awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I could be missing something, but I don't like this pattern.

You already have factories for `Circle` and `Square` - `Circle` and `Square`. :)

The code in your question unnecessarily hardcodes the class names in `factory` and then goes through some extra hoops by getting the names of the subclasses of `Shape` and then calling `factory` with those names.

A more direct way to generate the `shapes` list is

```
types = Shape.__subclasses__()
shapes = [random.choice(types)() for _ in range(7)]
```

> I have a situation where I could have multiple geometries being given. This is an over simplified example, but I am getting JSON response of various geometries, and instead of having to write multiple if statements multiple times, I thought using a Factory could reduce the issue: so Shape(JSON) -> Circle or Shape(JSON) - Square

This does not justify the `factory` as it is coded here. You could have a simple dictionary like

```
classes = {'Circle': Circle, 'Square': Square, ...}
```

or possibly create it dynamically with

```
classes = {cls.__name__:cls for cls in Shape.__subclasses__()}
```

and then call `classes[some_string]()` for the instantiation. You can even [dynamically instantiate a class by string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/python-dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported) using `getattr`.