# Use class from file based of name in string form (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, pytorch

Currently, I am importing every class I have in a python file in my main "Runner" script. The goal is to, based on a ***string*** given, instantiate the class that has the same name as the string given.

For example:

If there is a class called 'Test':

```
class Test():
```

if the String is "Test", it will call that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's seems a reflection case, that are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/python-dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported).

Example from ref:

```
module = __import__(module_name)
class_ = getattr(module, class_name)
instance = class_()
```