# How do I dynamically change which class I'm accessing using a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

An simple example of what I want to do is:

Main File:

```
import myPythonFile

answer = str(input())
if answer == "yes":
   classToAccess = "classA"
else:
   classToAccess = "classB"

myPythonFile.classToAccess.myVarible
```

File named "myPythonFile.py":

```
class classA:
   myVarible = 37

class classB:
   myVarible = 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getattr` to get an attribute dynamically. I believe this question already answered here [Dynamic instantiation from string name of a class in dynamically imported module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported-module)

```
import myPythonFile

answer = str(input())
if answer == "yes":
   classToAccess = "classA"
else:
   classToAccess = "classB"

myVarible = getattr(myPythonFile, classToAccess).myVarible
```

Comment: It worked when I implemented it in my pygame project like I wanted to so thanks again. :)