# Is it possible to dynamic instantiate a class written in a string without the need to write it to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instantiation

How can I instantiate the class stored in the raw string `my_class` [without having to save this string into a file first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported-module)?

```
my_class = r'''class A:
    def print(self):
        print('Hello World')
    '''

my_class_object = string_to_class()

my_class_object.print()
```

In the code above, I'm looking for an implementation of the function `string_to_class()` that returns an object of the class inside `my_class`.

The expected output of the code above is `Hello World`.

Comment: Any reasons for the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec): it supports dynamic execution of Python code.

```
import re 
def string_to_object(str_class, *args, **kwargs):
    exec(str_class)
    class_name = re.search("class ([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)", str_class).group(1)
    return locals()[class_name](*args, **kwargs)
```

You can use the `string_to_object` function to automatically create an object of the specified class:

```
my_class = '''
class A:
    def print(self):
        print("Hello World")
'''
a = string_to_object(my_class)
a.print() # Hello World
```

You can also build something more complicated:

```
my_class = '''
class B:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=0, d=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
'''
b = string_to_object(my_class, 4, 5, c=7)
print(b.a) # 4
print(b.b) # 5
print(b.c) # 7
print(b.d) # 1
```

And also:

```
class C:
    pass

my_class = '''
class D(C):
    pass
'''

d = string_to_object(my_class)
```

Comment: This answer does not help me in returning an `A` object as far as I'm concerned. Is it possible to do this by using `exec()`?

Comment: exec is the same as if you'd written the code in python, so `A` becomes part of the namespace you executed it in. i.e. after riccardo's answer, you could do something like `A().print()`

Comment: @ihavenoidea i updated my answer by allowing you to build any object on any class, even with parameters. Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: @RiccardoBuccoThis is great! Thanks a lot :) I'm having an issue though. My original example is a simplified one from my real problem. Your code fails if the class inside `my_class` inherits from another. Using your examples, if we have a `class B: pass` in the current namespace and the class inside `my_class` is for example, `class A(B)`, it gives me an error `KeyError: 'A(B)'`. Can you figure why?

Comment: It works! In the meantime I came up with another solution by using partition() `re.search("class (.*):", str_class).group(1).partition("(")[0]` which as far as my tests went, it worked as well. Thanks again @RiccardoBucco

Answer (score 2):

What about editing the string a bit?

```
my_class_with_new_object = my_class + "\nnew_object = A()"
```

my_class_with_new_object will be:

```
class A:
    def print(self):
        print('Hello World')

new_object = A()
```

The call `exec(my_class_with_new_object)` and it will create an object `new_object` of type `A`

Then just call `new_object.print()`

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I'll accept it in a few hours in case no other answers (possibly better) show up.

Comment: Upvoting, even if you could have simply improved my answer... This adds nothing to what I have already said