# import and create dynamically an instance of class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, python-importlib, import-module

I would like to import and create dynamically classes in Python.

What I have is a dictionary containing Scikit-learn classifiers such as:

```py
# list_classifiers.py 
AVAILABLE_CLASSIFIERS = {
    "Random Forest Classifier": RandomForestClassifier,
    "KNeighbors Classifier": KNeighborsClassifier
}
```

What I would like is to import dynamically my classifiers (they are all stored as classes in the directory `algorithms`) and add it to this dictionary such as:

```py
# list_classifiers.py 
AVAILABLE_CLASSIFIERS = {
    ...,
    "MyOwnClassifier": MyOwnClassifier
}

project
|-- algorithms
     |-- MyOwnClassifier.py
     |-- MyOtherClassifier.py
|-- list_classifiers.py
|-- ...
```

What I have tried:

```py
# list_classifiers.py 
import importlib
tree = os.listdir('algorithms')
for filename in tree:
    name = filename[:-3]  # remove .py extension to get only the name of the class
    importlib.import_module("project.algorithms."+name)  # sys.modules.keys() contains MyOwnClassifier
    # STRUGGLE GOES HERE: how to add my classes as objects?
    AVAILABLE_CLASSIFIERS[name] = eval(name)  # NameError: name 'MyOwnClassifier' is not defined
    AVAILABLE_CLASSIFIERS[name] = globals()[name]  # KeyError: 'MyOwnClassifier'
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Nelly

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic instantiation from string name of a class in dynamically imported module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported-module)