# Python: How do I import all exception from some module?

Tags: python, exception

I have the following scenario:
Program A uses library L. Library L defines some exceptions. If an exception defined in L is raised in A, I want to serialize it into a json and send it via some channel (e.g. redis). This exception is then received by some program B where I want to deserialize the exception and do something with it. In order to be able to deserialize the exception, B needs to know all the exceptions defined in L. How would I get all exceptions from L? Would it make sen to loop through all members of L and check if they are subclasses of Exception?

Comment: `import` operates on names, I don't think there's any way to filter imports by data type.

Comment: Perhaps all of L's exceptions are subclasses of a common base class. You could import that base class and use it in your `except` statements.

Comment: Not an answer, but as an alternative, if you add all the necessary information to the json, you should  be able to dynamically deserialize any exception in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported-module).

Answer (score 0):

In order to de-serialize the exceptions in `B`, `L` must be importable from `B`, with the same full name that it is importable in `A`.

If both `A`, `B` and `L` are part of the same Python package, it would just work. If `A` and `B` are in different packages, you'd better refactor `L` to live in its own stand-alone package (not depending from `A`), and make it a dependency of `B`.